# View Group Policies that are Removing Software

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have a software package that was installed with a group policy. It was subsequently removed by deleting the entry from "Computer Configuration -> Software Settings -> Software installation" (as shown in the example screenshot).

[image]

Once that software record is deleted from the policy object, is there any way of seeing a list of the software items group policy has marked for deletion? It seems like once you delete that entry there is no audit trail, no way of telling which software packages have been earmarked for uninstall.

It is true that good GPO naming could help mitigate, but this is not always possible in an inherited environment. What I would like to view software packages that have been marked for removal and possibly revert one or more of them as it seems like a GPO *may* be uninstalling software that was *manually installed by hand*...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can see the list of packages marked for deletion, this list is stored directly in the policy object.

Each package is in fact a child item in the GPO object, for example, here is the content of a GPO with 2 packages (viewed in ADSI Edit):

[image: LDAP View of a group policy object with two packages]

The technical documentation about [Group Policy Software Installation](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-GPSI/%5BMS-GPSI%5D.pdf), section `2.2.3.2.3 Package Creation Message` says that the LDAP attribute `msiScriptName` (in the package) holds the value "R" if the application is removed.

So, you can get a list with this LDAP query :

```
(&(objectClass=packageRegistration)(msiScriptName=R))
```

interesting attributes are:

```
displayName;msiFileList;msiScriptName;packageFlags
```

If you find removed packages in an inherited environement and you don't want them to be uninstalled anymore, I recommend you to destroy the GPO containing these unwanted references.

You should look at the `packageFlags` attribute too (documented in section `2.2.2.4.3 packageFlags Attribute Values`) to determine if the package is **Orphaned** (`ACTFLG_Orphan` => meaning that "clients that have already installed this application MUST
NOT perform application removals") or **Uninstalled** (`ACTFLG_Uninstall` => meaning that "The client MUST remove this application").